# TabHost inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm trying to add a TabHost layout inside a Fragement:

```
public class FriendsTabFregment extends Fragment {

    private TabHost tab;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friends, container, false);
        tab = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.activity_friends.tab);
        return view;
    }
}
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
        addNewTab("Friends", BasicFragment.class, savedInstanceState);  //Chat Tab
        setTabHeight(50);       
    }
```

for some reason i get the tab as null.
this is my XML:

```
<TabHost android:id="@+activity_friends/tab"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>


</LinearLayout>
```

any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Define your `TabHost`'s id as

```
android:id="@+id/activity_friends_tab"
```

and find it like this:

```
tab = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_friends_tab);
```

Have a look at this post for further understanding of `"@+id/"`

[What does "@+id" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4293192/593709)

[Android documentation source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id)

Comment: how come it works with no problems when i didn't use Fragment?

Comment: Did you replace it with `@+id/` while using Fragment?

Comment: [This post describe how to use TabHost with Fragments](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/)